# Vertically centering text

Tags: css, markup

Link to my [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ikejic/3/edit)

I am having a bit of unexpected trouble. I would like to vertically center the "Thing2" text. However the css property `vertical-algin: middle` doesn't seem to be working.

So I'd like to know 2 things:

1. Why isn't it working?
2. Is the way I'm doing it (by adding a main class to each then a styling class) the easiest way to do this?

**Note**
This is just a proof of concept of an overall idea that I have. So obviously class names and ids will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't vertically align text in that way, see http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/vertical-align

Try instead setting a line height on your container div equal to the height of the div if you just want to vertically align a single line of text.

e.g.

```
.metroSmall {
    line-height: 87.5px;
}
```

This is a nice post detailing a few different ways of vertically aligning html elements: http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/

If you are only supporting the latest browsers you can also use the new table, and table-cell display styles, which support vertical alignment in the same way that tables do.

e.g.

```
.metroSmall {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Bear in mind this won't work on earlier browsers such as internet explorer 6 though.

Comment: I'll give the check to you mainly because you don't have a lot of rep and answers like this deserve rep :)

Answer (score 1):

The way i vertically center things is to set the line-height to the height of the container

try adding `line-height: 87.5px` to .about

Answer (score 0):

Try Using This http://jsfiddle.net/YUruZ/

Use CSS style `display` property `table` and `table-cell`